# Calculus Summations

Tags: calculus, summation

Is there any way I can change a summation, say from $k=1$ to $n$ of the derivative of order $k$ of a function into closed form, or some form that would be more manageable?
Ex.  From $k=1$ to $3$ of $d(2x^2)/dx$ would be $4x + 4 + 0 = 4x + 4$
But how can I simplify this if I am running from $1$ to $n$ of an unspecified function $f(x)$?
What about the same but with integrals?

Comment: Without knowing anything about $f$, not really. In certain special cases (trig functions, exponentials, polynomials, ...) there are things that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want
$D(f, j, k)
=\sum_{i=j}^k f^{(i)}(x)
$.

There might be
some analogy with the
partial sums of
a geometric series.

What occurs to me
is the Taylor
(or MacLaurin) series
$f(x+h)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{h^n f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}
$.

There's a way of getting rid of the $n!$
I'm trying to remember.

Multiply by $e^{-h}$,
integrate from $0$ to $\infty$,
and use
$\int_0^{\infty} x^n e^{-x}dx
= n!
$.

We get

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^{\infty} f(x+h)e^{-h}dh
&=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-h}dh \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{h^n f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f^{(n)}(x)\int_0^{\infty} e^{-h}dh  \dfrac{h^n }{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f^{(n)}(x)\\
\end{array}
$

This is all I can think of 
at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n f^{(k)}(x).$$

Then 
$$g'(x)-g(x)=f^{(n+1)}(x)-f'(x).$$

You can integrate this differential equation with

$$\left(g'(x)-g(x)\right)e^{-x}=\left(g(x)e^{-x}\right)'=\left(f^{(n+1)}(x)-f'(x)\right)e^{-x},$$
then
$$g(x)=e^x\int\left(f^{(n+1)}(x)-f'(x)\right)e^{-x}\,dx.$$

Maybe not simpler, but the sum over $k$ has disappeared.

Comment: I understand how to integrate the differential equation, but how you got to that equation from the original summation I don't understand.  If someone could explain that step in particular that removes the summation I would be most grateful.

Comment: Compute $g'-g$ and see the cancellation. (Take $n=4$ for instance.)

Comment: Do you want $\sum_{k=1}^n f^{(n)}(x)$ or $\sum_{k=1}^n f^{(k)}(x)$?

Comment: @martycohen: fixed.